# List View Threshold - Future Planning

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, list-view-threshold

Regarding List View Threshold limits (LVT), I have done a lot reading and I am starting to wonder even with indexed columns will our current system scale?

What happens if we have a list called Clients and it has 15000 active clients & 3000 inactive clients (18000 items).

1. How do I display this data to my users without getting a threshold error?
2. How will exceeding the LVT affect other lists with Lookup columns pointing at the Clients list?
3. Will a lookup be fine or will it through its own error too or only views on the Clients list itself will require filtering?

**Server:** SharePoint Foundation 2013
**Note:** Need a solution that can be done via the web UI or SharePoint Designer. I am not a programmer.

Comment: Maybe this could help : https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114331/sp2013-list-view-threshold-changed , fyi SharePoint Online does not let you change the limit.

Comment: I have read similar posts on many sites, I currently have columns indexed and views filtering. But I have had other lists that exceed the LVT with views that are filtering on index columns have issues that restrict further manual filtering by the user, eg People fields.
I am creating a test list to see what issue can happen with Lookups to that list.

Comment: I want to follow this because of the reference to lookup columns.

Comment: Well as soon as my list exceeded the LVT the lookup column pointing to that list produces the standard error in place of the dropdown.

"This is a lookup column that displays data from another list that currently exceeds the List View Threshold... "

This definitely presents a problem as our Clients list is growing and we are already over the LVT of 5000 but we have increased it for other reasons and I don't want to continue with that approach.

Comment: So that adds a new question to my original, how do you work with a large list not only to present the all the relevant data for staff to look at as well as overcome LVT with lookup fields?
PS am I using these comments right by adding to them as I did above? I don't want to imply an answer by using the "Answer Your Question" button below.

Comment: I did a test with InfoPath as well that had a dropdown pointing the my Clients list. Even with a filter applied to the data source that would only return 1 item, it would error out. NOT until I brought the list count below the LVT did the IP form open without error.